# javascript calculation formula is not working

Tags: javascript

I have following JavaScript function to make some calculation with textboxes but when I call this function on textbox the it doesn't works. Here is my JS code

**Update**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>
function calc()
{
var pkrusd;
var pkrusd = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=txtpkrusd.ClientID %>").value, 10); 
var ratelb;
ratelb = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=txtRatelb .ClientID %>").value, 10); 
var res;
res = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=txtF5.ClientID %>").value, 10); 
res=pkrusd*ratelb;
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtpkrusd" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" style="text-align:right" onkeyup="calc()"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRatelb" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" Style="text-align: right" onkeyup="calc()"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please any one help me to find that what exactly i am missin in the code.

Comment: Don't forget the ID of you provide in the server-side ASP tag might not be the one used as the id of the input tag output in the client HTML. Run the application and view the source to check what Client Id is produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables aren't numbers. They are strings, so addition just concatenates them together.

Cast them to integers:

```
var pkrusd = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtpkrusd').value, 10);
```

Or floats:

```
var pkrusd = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtpkrusd').value);
```

Comment: What does your function do? It works, but you don't do anything with the `res` variable.

Comment: Ok Sir What have to do with res ?

Comment: res is just a variable. show it in a textbox or textarea. To see the value just raise a alert message containing res.

Comment: You should fill both textareas, then it should alert normal result. Set the default values to 1 or 0 like this "(document.getElementById('txtpkrusd').value || 0);"

Comment: Sir Does'nt working on keyup event please chek here 202.125.144.34:81/Calc.aspx

Comment: You want to do `document.getElementById('txtF5').value = res`.

Comment: sir when i do multiplication of both variables the txtf5 = Nan. why this is happening

Comment: You never defined `ratelb`. Use `ratelb = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRatelb').value, 10);`.

Comment: Sir Why the Nan Occurs when i enter the value in first text field

Comment: Because you are dividing the value of the second field (or the first) by a non-existing number, which always returns `NaN`. I'd try to check whether the second field is set before outputting the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Check your id's in the script. You need to use `txtRatelb` instead of `txtratelb`. They are case-sensitive.

Comment: Well, it has effect, as far as I saw at "202.125.144.34:81/Calc.aspx". But you do nothing to your res variable. Could you describe what is it for?

Comment: Sir I have updated my code now please check it is still not working